# Make Height of Field Dynamic?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to get a field in my parent report to adjust its height dynamically based on the height of a SubReport in the same row.  The SubReport could return anywhere from 1 to about 20 rows, and I want the field in the parent report to adjust based on the height of the SubReport.

Further, and I am pretty sure this is not possible, can I center the text in this field vertically?  I think CR only allows for horizontal alignment.

This is in CR 2013 sp7

Comment: what do you mean by adjusting dynamically? do you need the parent report field after sub report?

Comment: @Siva Kevin wants a field to get taller or shorter based on the height of an adjacent subreport.

Comment: 4444 is correct.  I want the height of my main-report field to be dependent on the height of the sub-report.  If the sub returns 5 rows, I want the field in the main to be essentially 5 rows high.  If the sub returns 15 rows, I want the main field to be 15 rows high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of these are supported by Crystal. Once the report data is generated and ready to display, vertical placement is largely automatic.

In theory, auto-generating line breaks in your field could push things down and *simulate* vertical alignment, but it would require extensive use of shared variables. Perhaps it's time to consider a different design for your report?

Comment: Thank you.  I was pretty sure this was the case, I just wanted confirmation.  Appreciate it.